# How to go to each directory and execute a command on specific file?

Tags: bash

How do I write a bash script that goes through each directory inside a parent_directory and executes a command on specific file.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
Parent_dir/
  dir1/
   acc.bam
  dir2/
   acc.bam
  dir3/
   acc.bam
... around 30 directories
```

This is the command I want to use :

```
java8 -jar /picard.jar CollectRnaSeqMetrics REF_FLAT=/refFlathuman.refflat STRAND_SPECIFICITY=NONE I=acc.bam O=output
```

Answer (score 15):

The usual idiom is

```
for d in Parent_dir/*/
do
     (cd "$d" && $command)
done
```

The `for` loop executes once for each directory directly within `Parent_dir`.  For each of those directories, a sub-shell is spawned; in the sub-shell, we attempt to change into that directory (which might fail, e.g. if we have insufficient permission), and if we succeed, then execute the command.  Whether or not we succeeded, the `cd` has no effect on the parent shell, so we don't need to worry about being in the wrong place there.

---

If you want to make it more robust, you might

```
    (cd "$d" && test -r acc.bam &&  $command)
```

to ensure that `acc.bam` exists and is readable in that directory.  You might also add a `test -w .` to avoid trying to run the command in directories that are not writable.

---

P.S. None of the above is specific to Bash; you can use /bin/sh for it quite portably.

Answer (score 3):

Loop over the files in the parent directory with `for FILE in *; do ...; done`.  If the file is a directory, `cd` into the directory, execute your command, then `cd ..`.

```
cd $parent_directory
for FILE in *; do
    if [ -d "$FILE" ]; then
        cd "$FILE"
        java8 -jar /picard.jar CollectRnaSeqMetrics REF_FLAT=/refFlathuman.refflat STRAND_SPECIFICITY=NONE I=acc.bam O=output
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

You could also use the filename in your command to avoid changing directories such as `I="$FILE/acc.bam"`.

Comment: Could you  please explain it clearly. acc.bam is not a directory

Comment: The first line iterates over all files in the parent directory.  The second line tests that each file is a directory (the `-d` argument).  If it is, it switches to the directory (`cd "$FILE"`), runs your command, then goes back to the parent directory (`cd ..`).

Comment: can I run this in one line?

Comment: You can run this on one line, but you'll have to add semi-colons in the appropriate places.  `cd $parent_directory; for FILE in *; do if [ -d "$FILE" ]; then cd "$FILE"; <YOUR COMMAND>; cd ..; fi; done;`

Comment: If this answers your question, could you mark it?

Comment: You don't need the `test -d` if you use `*/` as your glob.

Comment: @TobySpeight I did not know about using `*/` as a glob.  That's fantastic!  Also, I really like your solution with the sub-shell.  I've been doing this the hard way for years now; I can't wait to use your approach.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to go in every directory in your parent_directory and run java command. To return back to the parent_directory use:

```
cd ..
```

To get the list of directories in parent_directory you can use:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d
```

It will list only directories and only for the one nesting level.

The loop looks like this:

```
cmd="java8 -jar /picard.jar CollectRnaSeqMetrics REF_FLAT=/refFlathuman.refflat STRAND_SPECIFICITY=NONE I=acc.bam O=output"
for path in `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d` 
do
    cd "$path"
    $cmd
    cd ..
done
```

Java command was placed in a separate variable to make script more readable.

Comment: Could you please explain it clearly

Comment: You might want `cd "$path" || continue` so that we don't `cd ..` out when we hit an unreadable directory.

Comment: Here is a one-liner of what I am going to use this for... ```alias updategit='for path in `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d` ; do     cd "$path" || continue && git pull --ff-only; cd ..; done'```

Answer (score 2):

First, be sure that it is, in fact, necessary to have each of those directories as the working directory for an invocation of the command.  Well-written programs don't care where their working directory is, as long as they are given working paths for their arguments (and, if necessary, suitable `$TMPDIR` etc.).

If your command will work with actual pathnames, like

```
java8 -jar /picard.jar CollectRnaSeqMetrics \
    REF_FLAT=/refFlathuman.refflat STRAND_SPECIFICITY=NONE \
    I=subdir/acc.bam O=subdir/output
```

then you should be able to simply substitute the directory in each iteration of a loop:

```
const_args='CollectRnaSeqMetrics REF_FLAT=/refFlathuman.refflat STRAND_SPECIFICITY=NONE'
for d in Parent_dir/*/
do
     java8 -jar /picard.jar $const_args I="${d}acc.bam" O="${d}output"
done
```

(note, because `$d` includes a trailing `/`, I didn't add one where it's substituted into the command).

P.S. None of the above is specific to Bash; you can use /bin/sh for it quite portably.

Answer (score 2):

With `find` implementations that support `-execdir` (BSD, GNU, `sfind` at least):

```
find ParentDir -name acc.bam -execdir \
  java8 -jar /picard.jar CollectRnaSeqMetrics \
  REF_FLAT=/refFlathuman.refflat \
  STRAND_SPECIFICITY=NONE I=acc.bam O=output \;
```

Comment: Should I=acc.bam be I={} ?

Comment: @1_CR, `{}` is always going to be `acc.bam` (or `./acc.bam` with GNU `find`), and not all `find` implementations accept `{}` as part of an argument (`sfind` doesn't).